Sharepoint Online api/Web/Lists(guid)/GetItems POST rest api suddenly start ignore $top and $skip parameters
Sharepoint Online api/Web/Lists(guid)/GetItems POST rest api suddenly start ignore $top and $skip parameters here is my request details
POST _api/Web/Lists(guid'428350ec-589a-46d3-973a-fa6dc2e52f04')/GetItems?$select=Title,Id&$skip=5&$top=10
BODY
{
"query": {
"FolderServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/...",
"ViewXml": "</OrderBy>0</Value></Eq>someValue</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query></View>",
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.CamlQuery"
}
}
}
Please help I cant find any documentation about this, last week it was working perfectly but now it is failing, my pagination is not working, I cant use caml paging as it will require lots of changes in UI

If you are using the GetItems endpoint, it is important to ensure that the parameters are supported in the context of your request. The $top parameter is intended to limit the number of items returned, while $skip is used to skip a certain number of items. However, if the API is not recognizing these parameters, it might be due to changes in the API behavior or restrictions on the specific endpoint you are using.
You may want to check if there have been any updates or changes to the API that could affect how these parameters are processed. Additionally, consider switching to using $skiptoken for pagination, as it is recommended for handling large sets of list items.
